# Eigen - Calculate the Distance Matrix between 2 Sets of Vectors

Tags: performance, distance, linear-algebra, eigen

I need to create an Eigen array with all distances between each source and recorder position.

I have three Eigen::Array sx, sy and sz denoting the source positions and three Eigen::Array rx, ry and rz denoting the recorder positions. The length of source and recording position arrays are not necessary the same.

Using for-loops I can calculate the distance matrix as follow

```
Eigen::ArrayXf  sx, sy, sz;
Eigen::ArrayXf  rx, ry, rz;
Eigen::ArrayXXf dist;

for (int s=0; s<nrSources; s++ ) {

   for (int r=0; r<nrReceivers; r++) {

      dist(h,g) = sqrt(pow(rx(h)-sx(g),2.)+
                       pow(ry(h)-sy(g),2.)+
                       pow(sz(h)-sz(g),2.));
   }
}
```

I need to compute dist array like 500 x 1000 times for the experiment. Using the for-loop obvious works but it is probably not the most efficient method since it does not make use of the vectorization.

Rewriting the sx, sx, sz and hx, hy and hz into sxyz and hxyz arrays should be possible.

Is it possible to write the equation more efficiently!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to discard the inner loop in favor of an expression. By doing so, we allow calculations to be lumped together and hopefully enable vectorization. Assuming the `r` and `s` variables were declared as `Eigen::ArrayX3f sxyz(nrSources,3), rxyz(nrReceivers,3);`, you could then write the outer loop as:

```
for (int s = 0; s < nrSources; s++)
{
    dist.col(s) =
        (rxyz.rowwise() - sxyz.row(s)).matrix().rowwise().norm();
}
```

Here we use `rxyz.rowwise() - sxyz.row(s)` to subtract the s'th `s` from all `r`s. The `matrix()` is needed to give access to `norm()`.

Benchmark and compare to your implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the bit of code. It crossed my mind that I probably could remove the inner loop, but I think I would have gotten bogged somewhere half-way.

Comment: Since this operation is so easy to parallelize and vectorize I wonder if writing it in vanilla C code and letting Intel Compiler optimize it won't yield faster performance.

Comment: @Royi Possibly (that was what was in OP). Not everyone has access to ICC. In simple cases it might work, but even here, the one line is more expressive and compact than the vanilla code with the added benefits of knowing that expression templates and vectorization have been (at least somewhat) optimized and will run well on more processors than just Intels (e.g. AMD, ARM etc.) without modification.

Comment: @AviGinsburg, I can see your point. The problem is I'm not sure Eigen takes advantage of AVX / AVX2. Which in the above case could be very beneficial.

Comment: @Royi As of 3.3, [Eigen supports AVX](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=3.3#Vectorization). MSVC tends not to generate good assembly with Eigen. Try using gcc under Linux (even a VM gets better performance than Windows). Make sure to enable `--march=native`, `_DNDEBUG`, and `-O3` for a more fair comparison. Also, I didn't see that you enabled AVX in your project (unless VS2017 enables it by default, which I don't know).

Comment: @AviGinsburg, I didn't set `_DNDEBUG` and now I set it and results are almost the same. Eigen is ~x2.5 slower than vanilla implementation (With Multi Threading). If you look carefully you'd see I'm using GCC 7.3 (MinGW64). MSVC beat it. My remark regarding AVX was Eigen doesn't benefit much from it.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look on my project [Calculate Distance Matrix](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/Projects/tree/master/CalcDistanceMatrix).
I implemented various methods for calculating the Distance Matrix between 2 arbitrary sets of vectors.

Actually Eigen was pretty fast doing this (Much slower than the vanilla C implementation using MSVC).

Anyhow, another to do the above is:

```
void CalcDistanceMatrixEigen(float* mD, float* mA, float* mB, int vecDim, int numRowsA, int numRowsB)
{

    EigenMatExt meA(mA, vecDim, numRowsA);
    EigenMatExt meB(mB, vecDim, numRowsB);

    EigenMatExt meD(mD, numRowsA, numRowsB);

    // meD = meA.colwise().squaredNorm().transpose() - (2 * meA.transpose() * meB) + meB.colwise().squaredNorm();
    // Not even close to be as fast as MATLAB (Intel MKL???)
    meD = ((-2 * meA.transpose() * meB).colwise() + meA.colwise().squaredNorm().transpose()).rowwise() + meB.colwise().squaredNorm();


}
```

Just have a look on files.
You'd be able to see that I compared Eigen in both @AviGinsburg and the above method and it seems mine is faster (Though again, using Vanilla C is much faster than Eigen for that operation).